# Selenium Java - HttpURLConnection - No ResponseCode from url

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

sample code:

```
String Urlsample ="http://www.frysfood.com/i/community/";
HttpURLConnection conn =(HttpURLConnection) new URL(Urlsample).openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
conn.connect();
System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());
```

I'm trying to validate based on the response code. This  url gives me no response. Why?
And, How do i handle this issue and move on to next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any such issue in your code. But once you extract and print the *`ResponseCode`* you need to disconnect the connection as:

```
conn.disconnect();
```

---

However, even I was unable to get the *`ResponseCode`* from the url  http://www.frysfood.com/i/community/  but got *`ResponseCode`* as ***200*** from https://www.google.com/

Code Block:

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class getResponseCodeFromURL {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String Urlsample ="https://www.google.com/";
        HttpURLConnection conn =(HttpURLConnection) new URL(Urlsample).openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        conn.connect();
        System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());
        conn.disconnect();
    }

}
```

Console Output:

```
200
```

Comment: yes, i see a response from the rest of the link. Right now, i want to move on to next iteration if there is no response but the script stops running after it encounters no response. how do i handle this?